Jekyll - generate collection pages in multiple paths
Is there some trick to reuse the same collection to generate pages in multiple directories?
collections:

  documentation-app1:
    output: true
    permalink: /android/app1/documentation/:name/
  documentation-app2:
    output: true
    permalink: /android/app2/documentation/:name/

  # same collection - desired behaviour: generate the pages in multiple destination folders
  documentation-common:
    output: true
    permalink: /android/app1/documentation/:name/ # pay attention to "app1"
  documentation-common:
    output: true
    permalink: /android/app2/documentation/:name/ # pay attention to "app2"

Defining the same collection twice does not work, is there a better solution?
Solutions

I can create the common pages in each collection and reuse the content via an include, but if I use this solution I have to create the documentation files multiple times. Can I somehow get the above working?
I can make a symbolic link and use it for the second collection

